# swiper.js doesnt seem to finish animation in safari

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I inherited a project using swiper.js however it seems to be pretty bugged in Safari and I'm currently looking into what I'm doing wrong or a workaround. the image moves to the left when clicking the right navigation and vice versa. it also seems to leave a the previous slide behind on a very low opacity, I think its not fully completing the transition.

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import { Navigation, Pagination, EffectFade } from "swiper/modules";

import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    $('.swiper').each(function (index,value) {
        let swiperParams = {
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
            pagination: {
                el: ".swiper-pagination",
              },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
            spaceBetween: 30,
        };

        // if ($(this).hasClass('swiper-effect-fade')) {
        //     $.extend(swiperParams,{effect: 'fade'});
        // }

        if ($(this).hasClass('swiper-no-loop')) {
            $.extend(swiperParams,{loop: false});
        } else {
            $.extend(swiperParams,{loop: true});
        }

        if (typeof $(this).data('slidesperview') !== 'undefined') {
            let bp = typeof $(this).data('breakpoint') !== 'undefined' ? $(this).data('breakpoint') : 768;
            let data = {};
            let spv = 1.5;

            if ($(this).hasClass('swiper-no-preview')) {
                spv = 1;
            }

            data[bp] = {slidesPerView: $(this).data('slidesperview')};

            $.extend(swiperParams,{slidesPerView: spv,breakpoints: data});
        }
        console.log(swiperParams)
        new Swiper($(this).get(0),        
            swiperParams

            );
    });
}, false);
```

```
<div class="swiper swiper-effect-fade">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            {% for image in content.images %}
                                <div class="swiper-slide text-center align-items-center">
                                    {{ get_image(image, {
                                        src: 'subproduct_image',
                                        class: 'img-fluid',
                                        loading: 'lazy'
                                    }) }}
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    </div>
```

[example pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vkx4.png)

as you can see it is not centered, the image is centered in all other browsers but safari, you can also still see the previous slide on a low opacity

any help would be greatly appreciated

I have tried updating swiper.js to v10.0.4 as I did see some bug fixes for safari. however this did not help